# Shift instructions in Golang

Tags: c++, go, bitwise-operators

The go [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Arithmetic_operators) says:

```
<<    left shift             integer << unsigned integer
```

What if the left side is type of  `uint8`:

```
var x uint8 = 128
fmt.Println(x << 8)      // it got 0, why ?
fmt.Println(int(x)<<8)   // it got 32768, sure
```

Questions:

1. when x is uint8 type, why no compile error?
2. why `x << 8` got result `0`

For C/C++,

```
unsigned int a = 128;
printf("%d",a << 8); // result is 32768.
```

Could anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: `uint8(128) == 1000 0000` (binary). You shift that to the left by 8 bits, that's `1000 0000 0000 0000`, of which only the last 8 bits can be stored in an `uint8`, which is `0000 0000`, which is 0.

Comment: You ask why is `0` the result of `x << 8`. Let me ask, what result were you expecting when using a value of a type whose max value is `255`?

Answer (score 2):

The left shift operator is going to shift the binary digits in the number to the left X number of places.  This has the effect of adding X number of `0`'s to the right hand side the number  A `unit8` only holds `8` bits so when you have `128` your variable has

```
x =            1000 0000 == 128
x << 8
x=   1000 0000 0000 0000 == 32768
```

Since `uint8` only holds 8 bits we tak the rightmost 8 bits which is

```
x =            0000 0000 == 0
```

The reason you get the right number with an `int` is an `int` has at least 16 bits worth of storage and most likely has 32 bits on your system.  That is enough to store the entire result.

Comment: It does as it says in the name - shifts all the bits to the left. Adding a `0` is a by-product as it pads the space with `0`. If you shift right in C++ it preserves the sign bit, so may add `1` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Because `uint8` is an unsigned 8-bit integer type. That's what "u" stands for.
2. Because `uint8(128) << 8` shifts the value, turning `1000 0000` into `0000 0000`.

   `int(x)` makes it `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000` (on 32 bit systems, since `int` is architecture-dependant) and then the shift comes, making it `0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000 0000`, or 32768.